# Prestashop Amount 0 in the order summary by bank transfer module

Tags: prestashop

A bug already reported in old versions but which probably came back in version 1.7.6.8 of Prestashop and 2.1.0 of the transfer module.

An amount 0.00 goes up in the field, and yet during the recap, Prestashop does display the price and in the mail "awaiting bank transfer" the price also goes up.

Has anyone ever encountered the error?

thank you for your comeback

[image]

Comment: For anyone reading this, see also the thread on GitHub: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/20580